# Why is ColdFusion/Hibernate adding the entity name as a prefix to column names in generated SQL?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion

I am running ColdFusion 9.01 with all the latest hotfixes applied as of this writing. I've been using ColdFusion 9's Hibernate integration on a production site for well over a year and now need to relate two existing entities; however, Hibernate is generating incorrect column names for a many-to-many relationship.

My two existing entities are Presenter and Product. I have dbcreate set to "none" and am using the default values for autogenmap on a Oracle 11g database. So, Hibernate is not responsible for schema changes to my database.

Here is the new property I added to my Presenter entity.

```
/** Relation to any episodes associated to this presenter. **/
property name='Products' fieldtype='many-to-many' lazy='extra'
    singularName="Product" cfc='platform.shared.models.entities.Product' fkcolumn='PRESENTER_ID'
    linktable='PRESENTERS_TO_PRODUCTS' cacheuse = 'read-only' cachename = 'EntityCache' inversejoincolumn='PRODUCT_ID';
```

Here is the **invalid SQL** generated by Hibernate.

```
select count(Product_product_id) from PRESENTERS_TO_PRODUCTS where Presenter_presenter_id =?
```

I am unsure why Hibernate is prefixing the columns with the name of the entity. The SQL should look like this:

```
select count(product_id) from PRESENTERS_TO_PRODUCTS where presenter_id =?
```

As I diagnose this, I saved the HBXML files generated by Hibernate. I've included the full file for my Presenter entity below.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="Presenter" lazy="true"
        name="cfc:platform.shared.models.entities.Presenter" table="PRESENTERS">
        <id name="presenter_id" type="integer">
            <column name="presenter_id"/>
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="presenter_bio" type="text">
            <column name="presenter_bio"/>
        </property>
        <property name="presenter_name" type="text">
            <column name="presenter_name"/>
        </property>
        <property name="presenter_website" type="text">
            <column name="presenter_website"/>
        </property>
        <property name="presenter_company" type="text">
            <column name="presenter_company"/>
        </property>
        <property name="presenter_internalname" type="text">
            <column name="presenter_internalname"/>
        </property>
        <property name="presenter_logo" type="integer">
            <column name="presenter_logo"/>
        </property>
        <property name="presenter_description" type="text">
            <column name="presenter_description"/>
        </property>
        <property name="deleted" type="integer">
            <column name="deleted"/>
        </property>
        <property name="presenter_is_evangelist" type="integer">
            <column name="presenter_is_evangelist"/>
        </property>
        <property name="presenter_is_expert" type="integer">
            <column name="presenter_is_expert"/>
        </property>
        <property name="presenter_about" type="text">
            <column name="presenter_about"/>
        </property>
        <bag lazy="extra" name="Episodes" table="ASSET_TO_PRESENTERS">
            <cache region="EntityCache" usage="read-only"/>
            <key column="PRESENTER_ID"/>
            <many-to-many
                class="cfc:platform.shared.models.entities.Episode" column="ASSET_ID"/>
        </bag>
        <!-- This is the new relationship causing trouble -->
    <bag lazy="extra" name="Products" table="PRESENTERS_TO_PRODUCTS">
        <cache region="ATVEntityCache" usage="read-only"/>
        <key column="PRESENTER_ID"/>
        <many-to-many
            class="cfc:platform.shared.models.entities.Product"
            column="PRODUCT_ID" not-found="ignore"/>
    </bag>
        <!-- End new relationship -->
        <many-to-one
            class="cfc:platform.shared.models.entities.AttachmentImage"
            column="presenter_photo" lazy="proxy" name="Photo"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Much appreciated.

**** UPDATE 1 ****
I've added the inversejoincolumn column. I am able to access the products in my unit test with the following assertions, however, when I dump the entity, the error shows itself.

```
var p = entityLoadByPK('Presenter',276);
var pr = p.getProducts();
// Works
assertEquals(2,arrayLen(pr),'Expected 2 products');
// Also works
assertEquals('ProductA',pr[1].getproduct_name(),'Incorrect product name.');
// Also works       
assertEquals('ProductB',pr[2].getproduct_name(),'Incorrect product name.');
// Fails
writeDump(var=p,top=2,abort=true);
```

**** UPDATE 2 ****
I've awarded the solution; however, something is still off. I've attached a screenshot of the DUMP showing the remaining issue. ColdFusion says "[undefined array element] could not retrieve collection size: [Product.Presenters#0]". [image]

Comment: I think it has to do with your lazy="extra" because it is only bringing back the id with a link to the proxy object.  This might not be able to get dumped properly.  try lazy="true" and see what happens.  Not really sure but best guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I use a many to many relationship, i always have a inversejoincolumn attribute.  I think it is just guessing it because it is not defined explicitly. Here are what my relationships always look like:

```
property name="names" singularname="name" fieldtype="many-to-many"
cfc="cfc" linktable="linktable" fkcolumn="ThisId" 
inversejoincolumn="otherId";
```

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the definition; however, the problem still exists.

Comment: I've added some more information. I am able to access properties from my related entity; however, when I dump the issue remains. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Still getting the weird column in the generated query?

Comment: Query looks correct. Issue getting collection size during a dump now. I can access individual properties on my related entities--strange.

Comment: sigh... cfdump has gone pretty buggy lately